# Custom top navigation not working in site setting pages

Tags: 2013, global-navigation

I have created a top navigation user control which works fine in SharePoint 2013 site.

But on site settings and other administrative pages like site permission page, the navigation is not working.
 On these pages SharePoint default navigation is displaying.

I have checked that My master page is applied to these pages in which I have put my user control. Can you please tell me, how can I fix this issue?

**[EDIT]**

My master page is applying in Site Settings pages but my user control is override by SharePoint Navigation. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which master page are you using in System Master Page? Are they same?

Comment: It is my custom master page.

Comment: see my answer? is that making sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we came to a patch. I don't know the strange behavior of this issue. We took our code from contentplaceholder `PlaceHolderTopNavBar` and put below it and its working great.

But still master page requires contentplaceholder as if we remove it then it throws error that its missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your **System Master Page** is likely to be different. So apply the same master  in **Site Master Page** and **System Master Page**

**Site Master Page** VS **System Master Page**

**Site Master Page:**

The site master page will be used by all publishing pages - the pages that visitors to your website will see. You can have a different master page for each Device Channel. If you don't see the master page you're looking for, go to the Master Page Gallery in Site Settings and make sure it has an approved version.

**System Master Page:**

The system master page will be used by administrative pages, lists, and document library views on this site. If the desired master page does not appear, go to the Master Page Gallery in Site Settings and make sure the master page has an approved version.

[image]

Comment: I have checked this settings and in both my master page is selected.

Comment: Check the html markup when you are visiting your site sittings. Does your markup exist in site setting page?

Comment: No. My HTML layout is replace by SharePoint default navigation.

Comment: see this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/80498/21421

Comment: Can you explain that answer? I have checked using those classes in my css. But I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for your user control markup in the source of the site settings page. If you can find an empty markup such as a div or something then you can be sure that your master page is correct. Then you might be able to look into other reasons why the user control is not loading.

Comment: I have checked master page again and find that it is replaced by SharePoint default navigation. But the layout and look is of my master page.

Comment: Is your site based on Publishing site template or Team site template?

Comment: Its basically Team site but we have activated SharePoint Publishing Features.

Comment: You can perhaps try  making a copy of the default team site master page and add your user control to the master page to test further.

Comment: I have make a master page from seattle and put my control in it but still the result is same.